# Why Composer install is asking to allow-plugins?

Tags: magento2, composer

Why when I run `composer install` using Composer 2, I'm receiving these messages below asking to "trust" the Composer plugins?

```
magento/magento-composer-installer contains a Composer plugin which is currently not in your allow-plugins config. See https://getcomposer.org/allow-plugins
Do you trust "magento/magento-composer-installer" to execute code and wish to enable it now? (writes "allow-plugins" to composer.json) [y,n,d,?] d
laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin contains a Composer plugin which is currently not in your allow-plugins config. See https://getcomposer.org/allow-plugins
Do you trust "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin" to execute code and wish to enable it now? (writes "allow-plugins" to composer.json) [y,n,d,?] d
magento/inventory-composer-installer contains a Composer plugin which is currently not in your allow-plugins config. See https://getcomposer.org/allow-plugins
Do you trust "magento/inventory-composer-installer" to execute code and wish to enable it now? (writes "allow-plugins" to composer.json) [y,n,d,?] d
cweagans/composer-patches contains a Composer plugin which is currently not in your allow-plugins config. See https://getcomposer.org/allow-plugins
Do you trust "cweagans/composer-patches" to execute code and wish to enable it now? (writes "allow-plugins" to composer.json) [y,n,d,?] d
magento/magento-composer-installer contains a Composer plugin which is currently not in your allow-plugins config. See https://getcomposer.org/allow-plugins
Do you trust "magento/magento-composer-installer" to execute code and wish to enable it now? (writes "allow-plugins" to composer.json) [y,n,d,?] d
laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin contains a Composer plugin which is currently not in your allow-plugins config. See https://getcomposer.org/allow-plugins
Do you trust "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin" to execute code and wish to enable it now? (writes "allow-plugins" to composer.json) [y,n,d,?] d
magento/inventory-composer-installer contains a Composer plugin which is currently not in your allow-plugins config. See https://getcomposer.org/allow-plugins
Do you trust "magento/inventory-composer-installer" to execute code and wish to enable it now? (writes "allow-plugins" to composer.json) [y,n,d,?] d
cweagans/composer-patches contains a Composer plugin which is currently not in your allow-plugins config. See https://getcomposer.org/allow-plugins
Do you trust "cweagans/composer-patches" to execute code and wish to enable it now? (writes "allow-plugins" to composer.json) [y,n,d,?
```

[image: Magento 2 Composer]

How to solve it?

Comment: Check the "allow plugins" documentation https://getcomposer.org/allow-plugins

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Composer 2.2 comes with a new security feature, it does not trust plugins by default unless you specify it [in the composer file](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#allow-plugins), in July 2022 plugins will no longer be executed if they aren't specified in the `composer.json` file.

The new Magento 2 version [includes this feature](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/34873) in the composer.json, so you won't need to worry about it.

So, you have two options:

- Downgrade Composer to < 2.2 version.
- Update `composer.json` file accepting the request when running composer install.

```
{
    "config": {
        "allow-plugins": {
            "magento/*": true,
            "laminas/*": true,
            "cweagans/composer-patches": true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Composer just complains, without even logging what plugin was trying to run,
so how should we know what to add to `allow-plugins` object???

Answer (score 1):

Add the following in composer.json,

```
"allow-plugins": {
        "magento/magento-composer-installer": true,
        "magento/inventory-composer-installer": true,
        "laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin": true
    }
```

OR run following commands for whatever package the error is coming for,

```
composer config --no-plugins allow-plugins.magento/magento-composer-installer true
```